# Scroll through alphabet in text input form with Arrow Keys

Tags: html, text

Is there a way to iterate through the letters of the alphabet using the arrow keys in a html text input form?

The idea is to be able to scroll through the alphabet like an old arcade machine.

Thanks!

edit: trying to merge this with existing code:

```
function nameInputField(action, data) { 
    switch(action) {
        case 'focus':
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
input').find('input').focus();
        break;
        case 'value':
            return jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-input').length > 
0 ? jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
input').find('input').val().toUpperCase() : '';
        break;
        case 'submit_btn':
            if(typeof(data) != 'undefined') {
                jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
input').find('input').data('submitbtn', data).keyup(function(e) {
                    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if(key == 13
                    && typeof(jQuery(this).data('submitbtn')) != 
'undefined') {
                        var submit_btn = 
jQuery(this).data('submitbtn');
                        if(typeof(submit_btn.buttonRelease) != 
'undefined')
                            submit_btn.buttonRelease();
                    }
                });
            }
        break;
        case 'remove':
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
input').empty().remove();
        break;
        case 'add':
        default:
            jQuery('#canvas').after('<div id="user-name-input"><input 
type="text" value="" /></div>');
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
input').find('input').on('keydown keyup', function(e) { 
jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, 
'').slice(0, 18)); });
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for it. You can use up and down arrow keys.
The idea is to get the char code for the text inside element and then add one or subtract one from the char code since char code for the alphabet are like this 97 = a, 98 = b, 99 = c, ... 122 = z

For this example you have to click inside the text box first

```js
var letterIndex = 0;
$("#scrrollLetters").keydown(function(e){
  var originalString = this.value;
  var charCode = originalString.charCodeAt(letterIndex);
  
    switch (e.which){
      case 38:    //up arrow key
          if(charCode == 97)
            charCode = 122;
          else
            charCode--;
            
            
          this.value = replaceAt(letterIndex, String.fromCharCode(charCode), originalString);
          break;
      case 40:    //bottom arrow key
          if(charCode == 122)
            charCode = 97;
          else
            charCode++;
            
          
          this.value = replaceAt(letterIndex, String.fromCharCode(charCode), originalString);
          break;
      case 39:    //right arrow key
          if(letterIndex == this.value.length -1)
            letterIndex = 0;
          else
            letterIndex++;
          break;
      case 37:    //left arrow key
          if(letterIndex == 0)
            letterIndex = this.value.length -1;
          else
            letterIndex--;
          break;
    }
});

function replaceAt(index, replacement, myLetters) {
    return myLetters.substr(0, index) + replacement+ myLetters.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=scrrollLetters readonly=true value=aaaaaaaaaa />
```

Another example using label and document key down event

```js
var letterIndex = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  var originalString = $("#scrrollLetters").text();
  var charCode = originalString.charCodeAt(letterIndex);
  
    switch (e.which){
      case 38:    //up arrow key
          if(charCode == 97)
            charCode = 122;
          else
            charCode--;
            
            
          $("#scrrollLetters").text(replaceAt(letterIndex, String.fromCharCode(charCode), originalString));
          break;
      case 40:    //bottom arrow key
          if(charCode == 122)
            charCode = 97;
          else
            charCode++;
            
          
          $("#scrrollLetters").text(replaceAt(letterIndex, String.fromCharCode(charCode), originalString));
          break;
      case 39:    //right arrow key
          if(letterIndex == originalString.length -1)
            letterIndex = 0;
          else
            letterIndex++;
          break;
      case 37:    //left arrow key
          if(letterIndex == 0)
            letterIndex = originalString.length -1;
          else
            letterIndex--;
          break;
    }
});

function replaceAt(index, replacement, myLetters) {
    return myLetters.substr(0, index) + replacement+ myLetters.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id=scrrollLetters>aaaaaaaaa</label>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! Would it be a possibility to click the right or left arrow to spell out full words or initials?

Comment: thank you so much for this, it is helping me understand this concept a lot. I am trying to put this code into an existing script and I am wondering if you could help point me in the right direction - will update question

Comment: @cyo sure I cant try to do it. But first you have to try it yourself and please mark this as answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: sorry bout that! Marked as answered. Much appreciate the help. I have tried to merge, but the farthest I have got it making the text box disappear when I hit an arrow key :/

Comment: @cyo share the code so that i can see. You can put it there https://jsfiddle.net/ and click update then put the link in here.

Comment: Will the code snippet added to the original question help at all?

Comment: @cyo Actually ask anew question add it there so it dont get mixed here.

Comment: @cyo great let me take a look

Comment: @cyo what on earth is this.

Comment: apologies, this is just the complete js file

Comment: @cyo no i mean what platform is this. Because it does not show anything.

Comment: @cyo nothing is showing for me and I dont get it. sorry.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more? apologies for the confusion

Comment: you are unable to see anything in the results section you mean?

Comment: @cyo yes nothing is showing and I dont know what platform is this code for.